# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Message**

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'
```

**Description**

```
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Root Cause**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'
    org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.skipServletPathDetermination(UrlPathHelper.java:265)
    org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(UrlPathHelper.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.resolveAndCacheLookupPath(UrlPathHelper.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initLookupPath(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:491)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1255)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mvc-1</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**CODE**

[General structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5Y1.png)

[WEB-INF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXIST.png)
[Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxZjG.png)

Comment: We too got this error mesage after upgrading from Spring 5.2.9 to 5.3.1.

Comment: We've the same issue here after updating :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to downgrade javax.servlet-api to 3.1.0 and see if that solves your problem? That seems to have solved our issue.

Comment: I tried to explicitly add the javax-servlet-api 3.1.0 version into my pom.xml but the behavior didn't change, still got the same error

Comment: For me it was to update javax-servlet-api from 3.1.0 to 4.0.1 ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade the runtime environment. In your current runtime version of Java EE javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest does not contain a method with the name getHttpServletMapping. Java EE 8 Introduce the method getHttpServletMapping.Or make sure that you are using the same version for development and runtime.
References: [JAVA EE github docs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHttpServletMapping--)[Apache Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHttpServletMapping--)